# How to make Google chrome the standard browser every time i boot my pc

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell, script, standards

I was wondering if anyone knows how to make google chrome the standard browser every time i boot.
This is for a school pc bc the kids change the default browser a lot.
Maybe someone knows how to make a script for this.
And maybe you could explain to me how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are or have an Administrator in your school and the Computer is in a Domain Network, this could also be done via GPO

Answer (score 3):

Create a text file, named for example `browser-chrome.reg`, and copy-paste the
following text into it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.htm\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeHTML"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeHTML"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeHTML"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeHTML"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ChromeHTML"
```

Create another text file, named for example `set-chrome.bat`, with the following text:

```
registry /s "C:\path\to\browser-chrome.reg"
```

Now create a scheduled task to run this `.bat` file upon any user logon.
For details see the article
[How to create basic tasks with Task Scheduler](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the solution in [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsinternals/windows-10-how-to-configure-file-associations-for-it-pros).

For simplicity here are the steps;

**1.** On any windows 10 computer set the defaults that you would like to use via GUI.

*Settings > Apps > Default apps*

[Defaults Apps Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0OZU.png)

**2.** Run the following command on cmd.exe to export XML template based on currently selected defaults:

> Dism.exe /online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:C:\DefaultApps.xml

**3.** Copy the created XML file to a shared folder (if you want to change the defaults apps and automatically reflected on the other machines) or just move by a USB stick and then point this in Group Policy Settings on each machine.

*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer > Set a default associations configuration file*

Select *Enabled* and input the XML file location

[Set a default associations configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcLyp.png)

**4.** To make them not change the settings you should not give its accounts the admin rights.